# CakePHP: Internationalizing a web application - Design and Examples?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have a web application built using CakePHP framework and now I am in the process of internationalizing it. I started with the base set-up as outlined in the below article -

http://puskin.in/blog/2010/08/cakephp-manage-multiple-language-in-application/

and also add little bit of customization based on my previous question -

[CakePHP: Internationalizing Web Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774933/cakephp-internationalizing-web-application)

To completely internationalize my web app, I would need to translate my drop-down/look-up  content as well, like - categories, favorites, countries, bucket list etc.

What is the best way to design my tables and CakePHP samples? Can someone explain with a simple example and classes? Links or articles?

Lets say we have something like -

A user can create multiple posts, and each post has a category [science article, match article] etc in the drop-down and same we need to internationalize drop-down as well.

Answer (score 1):

Two hints:

1. Read the manual of cakephp.
2. Look into the code of a available application (maybe [croogo](http://www.croogo.org))

Comment: +1 for the great pointer, never thought I should looks into some open-source implementations of CakePHP. This is helping me in lot other ways - image upload, file manager etc.

Comment: Please, look always in source code... And thanks for upvoting

Answer (score 0):

My open source project is translated.
It call CandyCane. A port of Redmine into CakePHP.
I also imported translation files from Redmine, so CandyCane supports numbers of languages from the beginning.

https://github.com/yandod/candycane

It might be helpful for you.